# Custom TableView Cell ,check condition

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

am doing a custom cell for my tableview cell , am writing a condition in customcell class, if indexpath.row=0 create 2 images for cell else create 3 images ,

my custom cell class

```
if (appDelegate.rowIndex==0)
        {
            UIButton *lObjImageButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            lObjImageButton.frame=CGRectMake(150*0+12.5, 5, 150-10, 290 - 120+10);
            [lObjImageButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
            //lObjImageButton.imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            [self addSubview:lObjImageButton];

            UIButton *lObjImageButton1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            lObjImageButton1.frame=CGRectMake(150*1+10+5, 5, 150-10, 170+10);
            [lObjImageButton1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

            //lObjImageButton1.imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            [self addSubview:lObjImageButton1];

            imageButtonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:lObjImageButton, lObjImageButton1, nil];
        }
        else
        {
        UIButton *lObjImageButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        lObjImageButton.frame=CGRectMake(150*0+12.5, 5, 150-10, 290 - 120+10);
        [lObjImageButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        //lObjImageButton.imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self addSubview:lObjImageButton];

        UIButton *lObjImageButton1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        lObjImageButton1.frame=CGRectMake(150*1+10+5, 5, 150-10, 170+10);
        [lObjImageButton1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        //lObjImageButton1.imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self addSubview:lObjImageButton1];


            UIButton *lObjImageButton2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            lObjImageButton2.frame=CGRectMake(150*2+10+5, 5, 150-10, 170+10);
            [lObjImageButton2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

            //lObjImageButton1.imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            [self addSubview:lObjImageButton2];

        imageButtonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:lObjImageButton, lObjImageButton1,lObjImageButton2, nil];
        }
```

here the appdelegate.rowindex value am setting in my viewcontroller's inside cellforrowindex as appdelegate.rowstauts=indexpath.row

wen i run the application, the project is executed as my wish , 1st cell 2 images and remaining cells 3 images , 
but when i scroll the conditon is mismatching and making somtime 6th cell to be 2 images and sumtime 3 cell as 2 images and my 1st cell become 3 images..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    BSImageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    appDelegate.rowIndex=indexPath.row;

    NSLog(@"cell.index= %i",cell.index);
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[BSImageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }


    return cell;
}
```

The problem arises with scrolling.

Comment: because you are doing nothing when a reused cell come in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Whenever there is reusable cell just reset it (reset it to initial state then choose weather to give two images or three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that UITableView make these cells reusable for performance sake.

u have to make this condition in cellForRowAtIndexPath also.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString* reusableCellIdentifier = @"";
  if(indexPath.row == 0){
    reusableCellIdentifier = @"firstCell";
  }else{
    reusableCellIdentifier = @"otherCells";
  }
}
```

Comment: u want me to create 2 custom cell ?

Comment: no one custom cell as u did ..... but u have the tableview which contains these custom cells ... u have to identify your first cell as unique at the tableView to not reuse it again

Comment: this function is already there in your project somewhere ... u just need to add the conditions

Comment: Hy `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString* reusableCellIdentifier = @"";
  if(indexPath.row == 0){
    reusableCellIdentifier = @"firstCell";
  }else{
    reusableCellIdentifier = @"otherCells";
  }
}` works for me ......  solved !!!!!

Comment: you are welcome :D ... kindly choose my answer as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Use [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) instead of checking a condition in your custom cell.

Write two classes:

```
@interface KSRTwoButtonCell : UITableViewCell { ... }

@interface KSRThreeButtonCell : UITableViewCell { ... }
```

and then do

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL wantThreeButtonCell = (indexPath.row == 0);

    NSString *cellIdentifier;
    if (wantThreeButtonCell) {
        cellIdentifier = @"ThreeButtonCell";
    }
    else {
        cellIdentifier = @"TwoButtonCell";
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        if (wantThreeButtonCell) {
            cell = [[KSRThreeButtonCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
        else {
            cell = [[KSRTwoButtonCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define all button in cell.h file and properties all of them.
   Replace you cell.m file code by

   ```
    lObjImageButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   lObjImageButton.frame=CGRectMake(150*0+12.5, 5, 150-10, 290 - 120+10);
   [lObjImageButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
   [self addSubview:lObjImageButton];
       lObjImageButton1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       lObjImageButton1.frame=CGRectMake(150*1+10+5, 5, 150-10, 170+10);
       [lObjImageButton1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

       //lObjImageButton1.imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
       [self addSubview:lObjImageButton1];


           lObjImageButton2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
           lObjImageButton2.frame=CGRectMake(150*2+10+5, 5, 150-10, 170+10);
           [lObjImageButton2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

           //lObjImageButton1.imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
           [self addSubview:lObjImageButton2];

       imageButtonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:lObjImageButton, lObjImageButton1,lObjImageButton2, nil];
   ```

2.Add below content in your table delegate method before return cell;

```
if(indexPath.row==0){

            cell.lObjImageButton.frame=CGRectMake(150*0+12.5, 5, 150-10, 290 - 120+10);
            cell.lObjImageButton1.frame=CGRectMake(150*1+10+5, 5, 150-10, 170+10);
cell.lObjImageButton2.hidden =TRUE;

}
else{
cell.lObjImageButton2.hidden =FALSE;
        cell.lObjImageButton.frame=CGRectMake(150*0+12.5, 5, 150-10, 290 - 120+10);

        cell.lObjImageButton1.frame=CGRectMake(150*1+10+5, 5, 150-10, 170+10);

            cell.lObjImageButton2.frame=CGRectMake(150*2+10+5, 5, 150-10, 170+10);

}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create `- (void)resetCell` method which reset the cell to initial state and also create `- (void)configureImageView:(int)rowIndex` which configure image view in `BSImageCell`

```
- (void)configureImageView:(int)rowIndex
{
    if (rowIndex==0)
    {
        UIButton *lObjImageButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        lObjImageButton.frame=CGRectMake(150*0+12.5, 5, 150-10, 290 - 120+10);
        [lObjImageButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        //lObjImageButton.imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self addSubview:lObjImageButton];

        UIButton *lObjImageButton1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        lObjImageButton1.frame=CGRectMake(150*1+10+5, 5, 150-10, 170+10);
        [lObjImageButton1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        //lObjImageButton1.imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self addSubview:lObjImageButton1];

        imageButtonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:lObjImageButton, lObjImageButton1, nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIButton *lObjImageButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        lObjImageButton.frame=CGRectMake(150*0+12.5, 5, 150-10, 290 - 120+10);
        [lObjImageButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        //lObjImageButton.imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self addSubview:lObjImageButton];

        UIButton *lObjImageButton1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        lObjImageButton1.frame=CGRectMake(150*1+10+5, 5, 150-10, 170+10);
        [lObjImageButton1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        //lObjImageButton1.imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self addSubview:lObjImageButton1];


        UIButton *lObjImageButton2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        lObjImageButton2.frame=CGRectMake(150*2+10+5, 5, 150-10, 170+10);
        [lObjImageButton2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

        //lObjImageButton1.imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self addSubview:lObjImageButton2];

        imageButtonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:lObjImageButton, lObjImageButton1,lObjImageButton2, nil];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    BSImageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[BSImageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    else
    {
        [cell resetCell];
    }
    [cell configureImageView:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```